# Delete the letter 'e' when you type a phone number in a form input

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js

I have an app build on front end with VueJS and Element io. I tried to to the validation for phone number but I saw that letter you can type letter e in the form input.

I try to delete the last letter that the user typed, the 'e', or to not let the user to type that letter if I found that is 'e'.

I tried a few things that I found on the internet but didn't work.

This is the input with the latest try, that still doesn't validate:

```
<el-input 
  v-model="newUser.phone"  
  type="number"
  v-validate="{required: true, max: 13}"  
  name="Phone" 
  @keyup="newUser.phone ? newUser.phone.substring(newUser.phone.length, newUser.phone.length -1) : 'true'">
  <template slot="prepend">07</template>
</el-input>
```

This one was the prev version where I tried with vee-validate to not let the user to submit the form because the phone number is not valid:

```
<el-input 
  v-model="newUser.phone"  
  v-validate="{required: true, max: 13, regex: /^\d+$/}"  
  name="Phone" 
  :class="{redBorder: errors.has('Phone')}" >
  <template slot="prepend">07</template>
</el-input>
```

This works, I get the error, under input:  `The Phone field format is invalid`.

If someone knows how to delete the 'e' or not let the user to type 'e', please tell me, because that is more strict.

Comment: you can prevent it by keypress

Comment: I tried but still doesn't work

Comment: make listener to document?

Comment: please my friend show me what you talk about

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<el-input 
v-model="newUser.phone"  
type="number"
v-validate="{required: true, max: 13}"  
name="Phone"
v-on:keypress="isNumber(event)">
<template slot="prepend">07</template>
</el-input>
```

In Methods Function:

```
isNumber: function(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode
    if ((charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) && charCode !== 46) {
        evt.preventDefault()
    } else {
        return true
    }
},
```

Comment: My friend I tried but I don't get even on console something. The screenshots: http://prntscr.com/h2lizx

http://prntscr.com/h2ljm6

http://prntscr.com/h2lj9p